# Make JavaScript wait until websocket receives a reply

Tags: javascript, websocket, network-programming, async.js

So as the title says, I'm playing around with websockets. So far all good, except for the fact that I can't make the page wait until we get a reponse. Now, I do actually have a good reason to do this; the requests times are about 2-10 ms due it going to 127.0.0.1 , so barely noticable. It is however long enough for the page to progress long enough to get to a part where the response is needed.

As you can tell, that is kind of a problem.

I am using the normal JS socket interface on the client and a golang websocket library on the backend.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just embed your part where a responds is needed inside

```
socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
    // part where msg.data is needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some Web libraries like ReactJs/VueuJs?

If you are using some library that you can manage the Browser DOM, you can use a Spinner strategy. Wen, you page first rendering you send to the user at the first time a Spinner and before your data cames you remove the spinner and show your page. If you prefer you can use a Skeleton in place of the spinner.

If you are using react you can do something like this.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const Page = () => {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
 cosnt [data, setData] = useState({})

 useEffect(() => {
   socket.on('message', (data) => {
     setData(data)
     setLoading(false)
   })
 }, [])

 return (<>
    { loading ? <Spinner /> : <Screen data={data} /> }
 </>)
}
```